Negative Binomial SPSS Error
I was running a negative binomial regression in SPSS and received the following message:
The maximum number of step-halvings was reached but the log-likelihood value cannot be further improved. Output for the last iteration is displayed.
The GENLIN procedure continues despite the above warning(s). Subsequent results shown are based on the last iteration. Validity of the model fit is uncertain.
What does this mean and how can this be fixed? Happy to provide more information if needed.

Here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/logistic-regression-complex-samples-gives-warning-message-about-model-validity the same impediment, although in another procedure, is considered.

Thank you so much! Do you happen to know the statistical relevance of the message? I struggled to understand what it actually means

This is clearly an algorithmic-implementation issue, more technical than statistical. There should be some "inoptimality" within your input data or its interaction with the analysis parameters you specify. The inoptimality makes the computations ecperience problems, but those could be hopefully solved - as the Support page suggests.
